# A NullPointerException in the code

Tags: java

When I am trying to execute the code below, in the project it gives an error `manual array copy to collection`. On the other hand, when I execute the project in the JSP using NetBeans, it is showing `NPE` at a `for-loop`. Any idea?

```
ArrayList courseNames=new ArrayList();

String []values=request.getParameterValues("ToList");

for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++)
    courseNames.add(values[i]);
```

Comment: What happens if `request.getParameterValues("ToList")` returns `null`?

Comment: Is there any reason for using a pre-Java5 coding style? It's nicer to use `for(String value: values) courseNames.add(value);` though it's even better to use `courseNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(values));`.

Comment: For future reference, when code failed with an exception, you should list the exception (including line numbers) and ideally indicate where the lines appear in your code.  **Especially** with NPEs, which can occur anywhere and rarely have any guessable context.  See [http://tinyurl.com/so-hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Do you check that the value in `values` is not null? You should do that, as `getParameterValues` isn't guaranteed to return non-null in all cases. (In particular, it's not safe to assume that if `ToList` is absent, you'll get an empty array.)

---

Edit: The best way to do this is to do:

```
ArrayList<String> courseNames = new ArrayList<String>();     // Java5 good style
String[] values = request.getParameterValues("ToList");      // General style

if (values != null)                                          // No crashes
    courseNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(values));               // Implicit loop
```

Alternatively, use a higher level framework (e.g., [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)) to unpack the values from the request, but that's a much bigger job for you to do since they involve writing your code in quite a different way to before.

Comment: Thnx for the quick response.I'll check it now.

Comment: Hi donal, we are using dopost method in servlet.return type of dopost is void so we can't return values.

Comment: @david: No, I meant that `request.getParameterValues("ToList")` (which is a bit long to type out) is able to produce a `null`, irrespective of the fact that you're in a `doPost` context. You have to check whether it did so and only add the values to `courseNames` collection if it did not.